# Does convergent p-series equal $\frac{1}{p-1}$ ??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For p-series, I am looking at a derivation for integral test for the general case of $\frac{1}{x^p}$.

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}dx$$

For $p>1$, I have the integral equaling $\frac{1}{p-1}$.  What does this value mean?  It just means the integral has a value, meaning the series is also convergent/finite.  But, it does not mean the series itself EQUALS $\frac{1}{p-1}$  Is that correct?   We do not know what the $p$-series adds up to, correct?

Comment: The infinity symbol is done with the \infty command

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It's a good idea to place MathJax solutions in backticks, viz. `\infty`.

Comment: Do you need the derivation of integral test or the p series test ? Or you r trying to understand the convergence of p series in terms of integral test ? Make it clear so that i can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1

"I am looking for the derivation of integral test for general case $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$"

---

See the [statement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) of integral test is if $f(n)$ is monotone decreasing in the interval $[N,\infty)$ then $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}f(n)$ converges and diverges according to $\int_{N}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ i.e. if the integral is finite then sum converges else diverges.

Say if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$ then the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}$ converges if and only if
$\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{-p} dx$ converges.
And $\int x^{-p} dx=\frac{x^{-p+1}}{-p+1}$ now you see if $p>1$ then $1-p<0$ then$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{1-p}=0$
but when $p \leq 1$ then
$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{1-p}\rightarrow \infty$
 Hence the integral tends to infinity.

### Question 2

"what does $\frac{1}{1-p}$ mean ?

---

It does not mean that sum converges to that rather it states about the "finite-ness" of integral which is required to conclude the convergence.

---

### Question  3

"We does not know to what value it adds up. Correct ?"

---

If the sum never approaches to anything(diverging) then the answer is trivial. But if the sum is convergent then you can find using some techniques in complex analysis,this usually emphacised on a course on "analytic number theory". As far your 'general case' is concerned then it is a very [famous one.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function)

Comment: Thanks!    A lot!Thanks!    A lot!Thanks!    A lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, e.g. for $p = 2$ we have
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \neq 1 = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$